# Is there a way to set a default includePath in the VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the official document, it says that `C_Cpp.default.includePath` sets a default includepath. However, using the option in settings.json does not work(became translucent in the editor).

It seems that the `C_Cpp.default.includePath` option doesn't exist; however `C_Cpp.default.cppStandard` option works well.

So, is it a problem only limited to my environment or not?

```json
  "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
  ],
```

[edit]

Goal: Set an Intellisense works for a customized header; I am using my header since I need to modify includePath in .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json. For example, I could fix the file to include additional headers from `/home/foo` - and it's working.

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/foo/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

However, it is quite bothersome to fix the c_cpp_properties.json every time when I make a new workspace, so I was trying to set default template of the c_cpp_properties.json.

It seems that https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp gives some options for set a default setting which works when there is no property file in the .vscode directory of workspace, so I wanted to set C_Cpp.default.includePath. However, I couldn't set C_Cpp.default.includePath in settings.json(which opens from Preference: Open user setting in palette) while I can set other options such as C_Cpp.default.cppStandard.

So I am curious why I cannot override the default value, especially for includePath. I guess it has no bearing with other config like launch.json because it is limited to Intellisense(which means compile&debug works well without this setting).

Comment: Dude, you need to provide some more details. What are you trying to configure the setting for? And why do you think that it isn't working? Also, please post links for any documentation that you reference in your question. Also, I am guessing that your configuring this in your `vscode/settings.json` file, however, the vscode extension that adds C/CPP support, as far as I can remember, can be overridden in other configuration files, like your dbg config in `.vscode/launch.json` for example. Though I don't think in the launch.json file you append with C_Cpp, but that's not the point.

Comment: Its been a while since I have wrote Cpp in VSCode, and its hard to jump in and help you, when there isn't enough details.

Comment: @J-D3V Added some information. 

cf) "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "gnu++17" works(overrides default c_cpp_properties.json setting).